# Work with Redis in c++ locally, can I use redis-cpp library with complex configuration?

Tags: c++, redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

I want to work with Redis in C++. My idea is to use a library as simple as possible, so I'm working with: https://github.com/tdv/redis-cpp . What I need to know and I'm not sure where I can get this information from, is that if I have a provided complex configuration in Redis (with Redis Cluster and Redis Sentinel), can I use this library for simple gets/sets when my configuration is using nodes, master, slaves, etc.? Is it easy, or should I use a more complex library like redis-plus-plus to do the gets/sets.
I also wanted to know if it's possible to make a local installation and creation of a cluster (I know that for that I have to use redis-plus-plus) and then try my simple library (redis-cpp) to access and modify data. Everything locally, just to make a try.

Thank you so much!

Comment: https://github.com/tdv/redis-cpp#set-and-get-data

Comment: Why do you think redis-plus-plus is a complex library?

Comment: @for_stack well at least has more "things" than the other one, I prefer to use the simplest one.

Comment: If you want a simpler and more performant alternative and can afford using boost, consider using Aedis https://mzimbres.github.io/aedis/. For a comparison with redis-plus-plus see https://mzimbres.github.io/aedis/#autotoc_md17